# Add new contexts to canvas objects

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm making a library in javascript and I wanted to know if there was some way to add a new type of context to the canvas rather than 2d

```
var ctx.document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("othercontext");
```

where I would create a othercontext with all the normal 2d properties, plus some more. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You're making me curious! What do you envision in your new framework and how would it differ from the existing 2d/3d implementations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do this exactly, but you can hook the `getContext` method and return an extended 2D context that has extra properties and methods:

```js
(function() {
    // save the old getContext function
    var oldGetContext = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext;

    // overwrite getContext with our new function
    HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function(name) {
        // if the canvas type requested is "othercontext",
        // augment the 2d canvas before returning it
        if(name === "othercontext") {
            var plainContext = oldGetContext.call(this, "2d");
            return augment2dContext(plainContext);
        } else {
            // get the original result of getContext
            return oldGetContext.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }

    // add methods to the context object
    function augment2dContext(inputContext) {
        inputContext.drawSmileyFace = function() { /* ... */ };
        inputContext.drawRandomLine = function() { /* ... */ };
        inputContext.eraseStuff = function() { /* ... */ };
        return inputContext;
    }
})();
```

Thus, a call to `someCanvas.getContext("othercontext").drawSmileyFace()` will invoke the `drawSmileyFace` that has been added to the ordinary 2D-context return value of `getContext("2d")`.

However, I'm hesitant to suggest using this pattern in actual deployed code because:

- Your context name may later become natively implemented by browsers, and your overwriting of `getContext` will prevent that context type from being accessible
- More generally, it's usually [bad practice to extend functionality of host objects](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) like DOM elements, since host objects can (but *usually* don't) throw errors on perfectly ordinary operations like property access

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't been able to dig up anything that definitively answers your question, I would tentatively state that it's highly unlikely that you're able to define a new context yet in any implementations of Javascript (and even if you could, browsers probably wouldn't support it for a while). You could, however, modify already existing "2d" contexts with additional properties, perhaps by running them through a constructor?

Comment: I have been modifying the 2d context, by wrapping it in an object

Comment: Ah, okay. Well, that's probably your best bet, then.

Comment: I haven't worked with constructors. could you point me somewhere to learn about them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is impossible. I suggest wrapping it in an object or add methods to the context

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, that's not possible.

Canvas context's are intended to be something browser vendors (Chrome, Firefox, etc) create, not JavaScript/Canvas authors (you and me).

Aside from `"2d"` and `"webgl"`, The canvas specification states that browser vendors may define their own (experimental) contexts (like "moz-3d"), but again, not JavaScript authors.

Stick with adding new methods to the existing context. (Or making a wrapper, etc)